# How improve the performance of the query

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-12c

[image]

I think the correct answer is B and C. My reasoning:

The returned row is 1, but the Disk IO and Query is very high. So optimizer use a full table scan not index scan. B and C can make query choose index scan.

But the provided answer is A and E. Why, is there valid reasoning for A and E? Are my answers and understanding correct? Or something else?

Comment: From where did you get this answer?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit recommended answer. Maybe correct, maybe incorrect.

Comment: See [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Recommended by whom? Official Oracle training material? In case of some "free exam collection" the answer might be wrong.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks, I should not upload images. It's sample test from others. No data, and I do not have code too. I just want to know whether my answer and understanding is correct or not. It's not from official, I know the answer might be wrong. So I post here in order to let me understand background knowledge better.

Comment: What's your reasoning for chosing B and C?

Comment: @MichaelGreen The returned row is 1, but the Disk IO and Query is very high. So optimizer use a full table scan not index scan.
B and C can make query choose index scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A - Makes no sense. `employee_id` is unique, the query retrieves at most 1 row based on an equality filter, this should be a dead simple `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN`.

B - I don't think so. `employee_id` is unique, the number of distinct values equals to the number of rows. With huge gaps in a unique column, a height balanced histogram can still provide extra information for better estimates for a full/range scan, but this is an index unique scan.

C - Maybe, but very unlikely in a real scenario. The above query should return its result after a few block reads and gets (lets say, <10, index height + 1 table access). Instead, it took 453 disk reads and 797 gets. Maybe the query read the whole table instead of an index unique scan. In that case, decreasing MBRC would increase the cost of a FTS maybe up to the point, where the index scan becomes favored. Still, in a real scenario, with proper statistics, I doubt this would happen.

D - Maybe, but again, unlikely in a real scenario. "Decreasing" the index may reduce the cost of it. The clustering factor and number of leaf blocks do not affect the cost of an index unique scan. This leaves us with the index height, and yes, that may decrease, which means the cost decreases as well, but this difference is so small, I find it difficult to believe the database would choose a FTS with 453 reads over an index unique scan with an index that has a much lower BLEVEL (typically between 0..3, it is rare to have indexes with higher BLEVEL).

E - Makes no sense. Same as A.